# Suppressing jshint "error"

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint

I have a constructor, X, to create an object. Later in the file I add multiple methods via `X.prototype.method = function () {...}`. While I realize this is an assignment statement it looks and acts like a function declaration which does not require a semicolon.

gulp jshint insists that the missing semicolon is an error and that it must be written as `X.prototype.method = function () {...};`. It generates an error, not a warning that I could suppress with a -W### directive.

Is there anyway to suppress this error? I realize this is a nit and I can easily "fix" the code but I prefer the cleaner style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include semicolon's in your code. They are meant to conclude a statement. If you are setting a function to a variable, that is a statement. If you are declaring a function it is NOT a statement, and therefore doesn't get a semicolon.

There is no way to just enabling semicolon insertions on `var = function()` statements. The only thing you can do is enable semicolon insertion on the whole file. Put this comment at the top of your scripts:

```
/*jshint asi: true*/
```

asi stands for allow semicolon insertion.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it answers my question in two ways. First, there is no way to do what I am asking with JSHint as it is. Second, `asi: true`, gives me a sledgehammer approach to get what I want. It does more than I want, but it still is about the best answer possible given how JSHint works.

The first paragraph was not necessary - it restated what I had already put in the question (with the addition of asking me to please include semicolons which I clearly preferred not to).

Answer (score 1):

JSHint is right in this. You should add a trailing semicolon in an assignment statement. JavaScript however accepts code without semicolon. One way to resolve your problem is disabling the semicolon check at all with the asi option (http://jshint.com/docs/options/#asi).

Comment: This is not correct. In a declaration a trailing semicolon is not required and, in fact, JSHint doesn't complain about it. See http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13. So `function xyzzy() {...}` does not require a semicolon and does not generate an error message. It is required in my case because it's not just a function declaration, it's an assignment statement where the value being assigned is the function that is being declared.

Comment: Yes, it is only necessary for assignments. I wrote declaration instead of assignment. Thx for the hint.